# Maximum number of students who have passed exactly in one subject : $4$ set Venn diagram problem

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

> $50$ students attempted the midterm tests of class $5th$, the midterm
> consists of $4$ subjects English, Hindi, Maths and Science. The number
> of students passed in these subjects is $35$,$45$,$25$ and $30$. What
> is the maximum number of students who have passed exactly in one
> subject?

Total number of students = $50$
Let the number of students who have passed exactly in one subject be $A$, passed exactly in two subjects be $B$, passed exactly in three subjects be $C$ and passed exactly in four subjects be $D$.

As per the question :-
$A+B+C+D=50$
$A+2B+3C+4D=35+45+25+30=135$

Now in order to maximise $A$, we need to minimise the sum of $B+C+D$. So I thought to minimise $D$ first as I read somewhere that the minimum value of $D$ in $4$ set Venn diagram is given by

> $N-(N-A)-(N-B)-(N-C)-(N-D)$

But when I put in the respective values of $N,A,B,C$ and $D$ in the above formula,the result is negative. I am not sure if the above formula is wrong or is there any catch with the question itself.

So I thought that first I will minimise $D$ then, I will get two equations with $3$ variables and then I will subtract those two equations to get a relation between $B$ and $C$ and then proceed ahead but I am not able to proceed. Please help !!!

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your problem statement. What is required result in situation when there are 25 students that passed all English, Hindi, Maths and Science, 5 students that passed only English, Hindi and Science, 5 students that passed only English and 15 students that passed Hindi only?

Answer (score 2):

This is best understood by a "line diagram" rather than a Venn diagram.

From one end, draw a line of length $45$ for Hindi, and one from the other end, **avoiding the blank space**, one of length $35$ for English.

$000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ooooo$

$oooooooooo00000000000000000000000000000000000ooooo$

You can see that there are blank spaces of $10+5 = 15$ taking both ends, and that the numbers for the other subjects can be fitted in avoiding the blanks at each end

Comment: In the above arrangement, $10$ have passed only in Hindi, and $5$ from, say, Math, have passed only in Math